# Join Multiple Rows into One Row

Tags: mysql, group-by

Please Help

```
id username date   place_type sangat mode mode_name mode_arrival satsang_taken

1  homm 2016-08-01  C          1500   SK     AKY     08:32:00       VHJ
2  homm 2016-08-03  C          1220   SK     AKY     07:30:00       ABC
3  plk  2016-08-12  C          1508   SK     AKJ     08:10:00       ABb
```

Required Result

```
 username date   place_type sangat mode mode_name mode_arrival satsang_taken   date   place_type sangat mode mode_name mode_arrival satsang_taken 
   homm   2016-08-01  C      1500   SK     AKY     08:32:00       VHJ       2016-08-03  C          1220   SK     AKY     07:30:00       ABC
   plk  2016-08-12    C        1508   SK   AKJ     08:10:00       ABb
```

Basically there can be upto rows for any user that can exist so that all rows should be in Same Row.

```
SELECT o.*, o1.* FROM maindb o INNER JOIN maindb o1 ON o.username = o1.username AND o.date!=o1.date
```

**This is basically not doing well**

Comment: Try left join instead of inner join

Comment: No such Improvement,But Thanks for Comment..Any Thing Else i can do

Comment: Are you sure you want this output? What if there were 3 rows for homm?  :-(

Comment: Yes then three will be shown into one row or if greater then all of them

Comment: @Strawberry yes is there is way to do that??

Comment: Yes, but it's generally better to do that kind of thing in application code, if available.

Comment: no its not available. Firstly i have to make view with the Query and the View will be used for the Purpose

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create View using Inner Joins

```
CREATE or REPLACE VIEW object(u_name,1_week,1_date,1_placet,1_sangat,1_mode ,1_mname,1_marr,1_stkn,1_sname,1_sbegin,1_s_end,1_day,2_week,2_date,2_placet,2_sangat,2_mode ,2_mname,2_marr,2_stkn,2_sname,2_sbegin,2_s_end,2_day,3_week,3_date,3_placet,3_sangat,3_mode ,3_mname,3_marr,3_stkn,3_sname,3_sbegin,3_s_end,3_day) AS 

(SELECT DISTINCT
maindb.username,
p1.week,p1.date,p1.place_type,p1.sangat,p1.mode,p1.mode_name,p1.mode_arrival,p1.satsang_taken,p1.saint_name,p1.satsangbegintime,p1.satsangendtime,p1.today,
p2.week,p2.date,p2.place_type,p2.sangat,p2.mode,p2.mode_name,p2.mode_arrival,p2.satsang_taken,p2.saint_name,p2.satsangbegintime,p2.satsangendtime,p2.today,
p3.week,p3.date,p3.place_type,p3.sangat,p3.mode,p3.mode_name,p3.mode_arrival,p3.satsang_taken,p3.saint_name,p3.satsangbegintime,p3.satsangendtime,p3.today

FROM maindb

INNER JOIN maindb AS p1 ON p1.username=maindb.username AND p1.week=1
INNER JOIN maindb AS p2 ON p2.username=maindb.username AND p2.week=2
INNER JOIN maindb AS p3 ON p3.username=maindb.username AND p3.week=3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT o.*, o1.* FROM maindb o LEFT JOIN maindb o1 ON o.username = o1.username AND o.date!=o1.date where o.id = (select min(id) from maindb o2 where o2.username = o.username)
```

Comment: No Its Not Working 1st Row is Repeating and i also want that all of the three rows should be in one row and if there is more than one row available for homm then all rows will be into one Row..